# Divide one single URL parameter into three values for the back end

Tags: java, web-applications, websphere, url-parameters, wcs

For a programming job I have to break up one single URL parameter into three different fields to make it back-end compatible:

**URL:** sampleurl/PickUpPoint/SelectedView?zip=4431AC&street=Nieuwe+Rijksweg%2C+4B&orderId=6020002&

**Code Snippets**

```
private String street = null;

public void setRequestProperties(TypedProperty reqProperties) throws ECException {
street = reqProperties.getString("street");
AddressBean.setAddress1(street);
```

result in database:

```
Address1 = Nieuwe Rijksweg 4B
```

**However**, the backend is set up in a way that the street address is divided in three different fields:

```
Address1 Streetname
Address2 Number
Address3 addition to the number such as 'a' (if applicable)
```

**Unfortunately** I cannot change the backend set up anymore..

What kind of code/algorithm can I use to make this URL parameter compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression is your friend. RegEx is a notation for String patterns. You can search for these patterns in Strings to get any matches.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "^(.+)?(?= [0-9])" ); // regular expression for street
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( originalString );

if ( matcher.find() )
    String street = matcher.group();

String number = // regex would be: [0-9]+
String addition = // zero or more characters after a number
```

I don't know the exact notation for the regular expressions, but you can google that easily.

There is also a nice plugin for eclipse to test regex, I think it is called QuickREx.

**EDIT:** I have added some code to show how it works.

*Short regex explanation:*

```
^(.+)?(?= [0-9])   // match everything from beginning until a blank followed by a number
[0-9]+    // match 1 or more digits
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Why is that not an answer? _"What kind of code/algorithm can I use to make this URL parameter compatible?"_ is the question, so suggesting to use regex to split the String is a perfect valid answer in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, technically, that's a valid answer, but giving an example is the least you can do.

Comment: Thanks, I will look in to this. However, if someone can provide an example this would be greatly appreciated.